# .Net C# DataTables and DataSets, How to relate tables

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

How do you take a couple of data tables and put them in a dataset and relate (that doesn't even sound like correct English) them?

I know how to create datatables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example from one of my classes

```
// create the relationship between Booking and Booking_MNI
DataRelation relBookingMNI;                         
relBookingMNI = new DataRelation("BookingToBookingMNI",dsBooking.Tables["Booking"].Columns["Record_Id"],dsBooking.Tables["Booking_MNI"].Columns["booking_record_id"]);
dsBooking.Relations.Add(relBookingMNI);
```

dsBooking is my main dataset that contains 2 tables Booking and Booking_MNI
Where the Record_Id is the primary key and booking_record_id is the foreign key

I changed the code below to match my first example. But I think this is what you are looking for. In our production code this will produce the plus "+" symbol to the left of the row which would allow you to drill into the related table. Again I took production code and made it look like the first example so I don't know if it will compile but it should get you going in the right direction.

```
DataTable dtBooking = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dtBooking_MNI = ds.Tables[1];

dtBooking.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dtBooking.Columns["Record_Id"]};
dtBooking_MNI.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dtBooking_MNI.Columns["booking_Record_Id"]};

/* Setup DataRelation between the DataTables */
DataColumn[] dcBookingColsArray = new DataColumn[1] {dtBooking.Columns["Record_Id"]};
DataColumn[] dcBookingMNIColsArray = new DataColumn[1] {dtBooking_MNI.Columns["booking_record_Id"]};

DataRelation relBooking_To_MNI = new DataRelation("Booking_To_MNI",dcBookingColsArray,dcBookingMNIColsArray);
ds.Relations.Add(relBooking_To_MNI_Units);

// grid where you want to display the relationship
grdBooking.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: So that made sense and worked.  Hmm, now the idiot question, how do  yo get the data out?  I'm using this with a GridView control and am wondering how to get the data out of the joined table?  So lets say my main table contains Publications and my joined table is Owners (not all publications have owners) how do I get the owner information to show in my grid view?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the DataRelation class.  It is what is used in a DataSet to relate two DataTables together.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you've got your DataTables named "orders" and "orderDetails".  You want to create a relationship between them by their OrderNumber columns.  We'll assume that orders is the parent and orderDetails is the child.  We want to loop through the orders and then print each one's related sub-totals.

```
DataSet orderData = new DataSet("OrderData");

orderData.Tables.Add(orders);
orderData.Tables.Add(orderDetails);

orderData.Relations.Add("Order_OrderDetails", orders.Columns["OrderNumber"], orderDetails.Columns["OrderNumber"]);
```

Now, when you want to use that relationship somewhere else in your code:

```
DataRelation orderRelation = orderData.Relations["Order_OrderDetails"];

foreach (DataRow order in orders.Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Subtotals for Order {0}:", order["OrderNumber"]);

   foreach (DataRow orderDetail in order.GetChildRows(orderRelation))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Order Line {0}: {1}", orderDetail["OrderLineNumber"], string.Format("{0:C}", orderDetail["Price"]));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, but how would that work in conjunction with a gridview control?

Comment: There are many different ways to go about using a DataRelation in a GridView.  By far, the easiest way to handle this would be to just create a LINQ to DataSet query and bind that.  You can also create a combined DataTable to bind to your GridView and fill it by looping through parent and child rows, similar to my example.  Then just bind that DataTable (alternatively, if this is 1-1, you can add columns to the parent table and fill it through the same looping structure).  Also, you can do this looping in your page and set the GridView's values explicitly.

Comment: Lloyd, how do I "... do this looping in your page and set the GridView's values explicity?"

Answer (score 1):

try this here is two table 1. categories & 2. Products

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Categories; SELECT * FROM Products";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "CategoriesAndProducts");     //CategoriesAndProducts dataset

        string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();  
        string s1 = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString(); 

        Console.WriteLine(s);  //from categories [0][0] like Electronic
        Console.WriteLine(s1); //from Products  [0][0]  like LG
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into LINQ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx

Comment: I have but have never used it before and am worried that it will take too much time to get up to speed.

Comment: Worth while taking some looks at - if you have the time available

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for an [orm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) solution like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx), [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) or [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)?

Appologies if I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2005 or later try the following:
Right-click your project and select "Add/NewItem...", then choose DataSet from the wizard, which will create you some xsd and open the dataset designer.
Now you can create multiple tables, add columns to each table and draw relations (foreign key, with/without cascading...) between those tables.
in the autogenerated [YourNewDataSet}.Designer.cs-file, you will find the source code for these relations.
Something like this:

```
this.relationFK_DataTable2_DataTable1 = new global::System.Data.DataRelation("FK_DataTable2_DataTable1", new global::System.Data.DataColumn[] {
                    this.tableDataTable2.asdfasColumn}, new global::System.Data.DataColumn[] {
                    this.tableDataTable1.asdfaColumn}, false);
```

As always you can strip quite some portion of this code, if you code by hand instead of using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateRelation() 
 {
   // Get the DataColumn objects from two DataTable objects 
   // in a DataSet. Code to get the DataSet not shown here.
   DataColumn parentColumn = 
   DataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustID"];
   DataColumn childColumn = 
   DataSet1.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustID"];
   // Create DataRelation.
   DataRelation relCustOrder;
   relCustOrder = new DataRelation("CustomersOrders", 
   parentColumn, childColumn);
   // Add the relation to the DataSet.
   DataSet1.Relations.Add(relCustOrder);
  }
```